# how to implement Google Login API in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, google-api, google-signin

So I was using the guide and codes from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

When I clicked the button, it works fine, it will redirect me to google login page, and no problem occurs during authentication.

Once finished, it redirected me back to the page (vue component) where the button is located. In theory it should call `onSignIn` method and print out info with `console.log`, but it didn't happen.

Somehow Vue was not able to excute `data-onsuccess="onSignIn"`. I tried to change `data-onsuccess` to dynamic props (`:data-onsuccess`) or event handling (`@data-onsuccess`), both of these does not work either.

Does anyone countered this issue before? Or there's special way to implement it on Vue?

Comment: Please include more code. How do you define `onSignIn` function? Is it global function or inside Vue component?

Comment: @ittus it's inside a vue component

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`data-onsuccess="onSignIn"` is looking for a global `onSignIn` function. You need to put `onSignIn` outside of Vue component.

Another way is using `gapi.signin2.render` to render sign-in button, then you can use `onSignIn` inside Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div id="google-signin-button"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    gapi.signin2.render('google-signin-button', {
      onsuccess: this.onSignIn
    })
  },
  methods: {
    onSignIn (user) {
      const profile = user.getBasicProfile()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

For more reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

Comment: it won't call the `onSignIn` unless I refresh the page, what's the problem in here?

Comment: Or If I wanted to put it outside the vue component, where should I put it?

Comment: You can put it in `main.js`

Answer (score 7):

If someone is looking for a Vue 3 plugin for using the [Google Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web) to implement features like Sign In With Google, One-tap sign-up and Automatic sign-in, you can use the plugin [vue3-google-login](https://yobaji.github.io/vue3-google-login/) which I recently created for one of my project.

Here is a sample code to create a simple Google Sign In Button using [vue3-google-login](https://yobaji.github.io/vue3-google-login/)

First [initialise the plugin in main.js](https://yobaji.github.io/vue3-google-login/#initialize-the-plugin) with your [Google API client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid)

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vue3GoogleLogin from 'vue3-google-login'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(vue3GoogleLogin, {
  clientId: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'
})

app.mount('#app')
```

Then use GoogleLogin component like this

```js
<script setup>
const callback = (response) => {
  console.log("Handle the response", response)
}
</script>

<template>
  <GoogleLogin :callback="callback"/>
</template>
```

Comment: Oh this was really helpful ...

Answer (score 6):

In case somebody needs a plugin to start working right away without too much setup, try this [vue-google-signin-button-directive](https://github.com/mejiamanuel57/vue-google-signin-button-directive).

Comment: I am normally opposed to using libraries for something like this, but this one is the simplest by far.

Comment: don't understand why it's implemented as a directive instead of a component.

Comment: Because a directive will give you more flexibility in terms of the design and props of your button. @Pithikos